# Loop to read the body with gmail api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail-api

I would like to implement the Gmail API into one of my projects. So I've followed the quickstart tutorial maid by google to do it, and it's working great.

```
require "google/apis/gmail_v1"
require "googleauth"
require "googleauth/stores/file_token_store"
require "fileutils"

OOB_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".freeze
APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Ruby Quickstart".freeze
CREDENTIALS_PATH = "credentials.json".freeze
# The file token.yaml stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
TOKEN_PATH = "token.yaml".freeze
SCOPE = Google::Apis::GmailV1::AUTH_GMAIL_MODIFY

##
# Ensure valid credentials, either by restoring from the saved credentials
# files or intitiating an OAuth2 authorization. If authorization is required,
# the user's default browser will be launched to approve the request.
#
# @return [Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials] OAuth2 credentials
def authorize
  client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file CREDENTIALS_PATH
  token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new file: TOKEN_PATH
  authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new client_id, SCOPE, token_store
  user_id = "default"
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials user_id
  if credentials.nil?
    url = authorizer.get_authorization_url base_url: OOB_URI
    puts "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the " \
         "resulting code after authorization:\n" + url
    code = "XXXX"
    credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
      user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI
    )
  end
  credentials
end

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize

messages = []
next_page = nil
begin
result = service.list_user_messages('me', max_results: [500].min, page_token: next_page)
messages += result.messages
break if messages.size >= 500
next_page = result.next_page_token
end while next_page

puts "Found #{messages.size} messages"

messages.each do |message| 
    puts "- #{message.thread_id }"
end
```

In the project, we made a loop with the labels, and all is working correctly. Now, I would like to do the same with my emails. As you can see on the following script, I'm looping the id of the mails. This is working without problem, but when I'm trying to loop the content or any other [attributes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages) described on the documentation, it's rendering an array empty.

```
puts "- #{message.body }"
```

Do you have any leads that allow me to identify my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reproduce with the Try this API for [listing messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) that

### the response contains only the thread Ids and message Ids.

To retrieve `message.body` you need to use the method [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) specifying as parameter the message Id you retrieved with `Users.messages: list`.